# jQuery z-index doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, z-index

i have a menu and on hover i fade a box in. Behind this box i have a small icon and i want to move it in front of the box so you can see it on hover.

Here is my menu >  [Navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/gPbv6/1/)

I tried it with that `jQuery(this).find(".flyer").css("z-index", 10000);`
but it stays behind. 
How could i manage that problem?

greets Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements, so you need to give `.flyer` a `position`, like this:

```
.flyer{
    margin: -75px 0 0 0;
    width:53px;
    height:74px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Here's your example/fiddle edited to work](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gPbv6/2/), we're just calling this on hover:

```
$(this).find(".flyer").css("z-index", 10000);
```

and this on hover out:

```
$(this).find(".flyer").css("z-index", "auto");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you reference the proper element with the .flyer selector and z-index does not do the trick, try with the [zoom attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189(VS.85).aspx).